# Decoupling Partial Views in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, partial-views

I'm trying to figure out a decoupled way of communicating between my partial views. For example, if I have one partial view that displays a menu of items and if a have another partial view that needs to be refreshed every time a menu item is selected, how do I do this without hard coding the JS call into my menu partial view?

Ive tried searching for ideas but havn't come up with much:(

In the days of ASP.OLD, I would create a event handler on my user control and then have other controls subscribe to that event handler to listen for a raised event. This created a decoupling between that controls and one control did not need to know anything about the other control.

I'm thinking there must be a design pattern that lets me accomplish this with MVC Partial Views ???

Thank You for your thoughts

Earl

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the *Mediator* design pattern. In short, a mediator encapsulates the interaction of separate objects into a single interface so that they don't have to communicate directly. There are a variety of resources out there on the topic but here is a decent example:

http://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern

Comment: Thank you, Tony. I used this as a starting place to come up with a pattern that works for me. Mostly I needed it for JavaScript code and found out how to create a triggers and listeners to accomplish what I needed.